# Wicket wantOnSelectionChangedNotifications changes input textfield

Tags: java, html, wicket

I have a simple form in wicket, there is an field with template name and few checkboxes, with overriden onSelectionChange methods. When I put some text in textfield from page parameters

```
@Override
            protected void onInitialize() {
                super.onInitialize();
                if (PageParameters.get("templateName").toString() != null) {
                    OfferTemplate offerTemplate = huskyService.getTemplate(PageParameters.get("templateName").toString());

                    offerTemplateFormModel.setTemplateName(offerTemplate.getTemplateName());
```

and I mark checkbox

```
add(new CheckBox("htmlCheckbox",  new Model<Boolean>(Boolean.TRUE)) {
            protected boolean wantOnSelectionChangedNotifications() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onSelectionChanged(Boolean newSelection) {
                super.onSelectionChanged(newSelection);
                isHtmlVisible = !isHtmlVisible;
                htmlTemplate.setRequired(isHtmlVisible);
                offerTemplateFormModel.setHtmlCheckbox(isHtmlVisible);
                htmlDiv.setVisible(isHtmlVisible);
            }
        });
```

it automatically add for words in my input field. for example it was "hey" then after click it will be "hey;hey" and etc.
Maybe someone could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your input's name is "templateName"? In that case that parameter will be sent twice when `wantOnSelectionChangedNotifications` triggers a request.

Please give your input a different name than your page parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `offerTemplateFormModel.setTemplateName(...)` is called again.

This is strange because `onInitialize()` is called only once for the lifetime of a Page/Component. If you were using `onConfigure()` then it would be normal behavior to observe.

If the page is stateless then a new instance is created for each request and then most probably the value in the request parameters accumulates the old values.